# If statements with Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is in an example with the purpose of learning.

Let’s say I’m doing an application to pick your favorite basketball team and your favorite basketball player of that team.

Se let's say that I want my favorite team to be the 'Lakers', then to be displayed a form with all the Lakers players and then pick 'Kobe Bryant'.

Would the code be something like this, or what is the correct way of having if statements to be displayed in the form? (If there is a way)

```
  <%= form_for @basketball do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :team, "What's your favorite Team?" %><br />
        <%= f.select(:team, options_for_select([['Lakers'],['Heat'])) %><br />  

    <% f.label :player, "What's your favorite player?" %><br />
      #I know this is terrible  
      <% if :team == "Lakers" %>
            <%= f.select(:player, options_for_select([['Kobe Bryant'],['Jeremy Lin'],['Carlos Boozer'])) %><br />
      <% elsif :team == "Heat" %>
            <%= f.select(:player, options_for_select([['Dwayne Wade'],['Chris Bosh'],['Mario Chalmers'])) %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is *kinda* correct. Except you don't want to cause refreshing of the page anytime someone picks/changes a favorite team. So the second part would probably need to be written as an AJAX call back to rails.

So the general flow would be:

1. Present a selection of teams
2. User chooses team and hits 'next' button
3. The 'next' button sends a remote request back to rails that looks up the team by id and returns a list of players.
4. Rails then fires of some JS template that loads that list of players into the view dynamically.

Here is a link to point you in the right direction:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

The only other option is to load all players and teams into the view, hide them with CSS, then selectively show/hide them via JS/jQuery.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to comment here if you run across anything along the way. If this question was helpful, would mind marking it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in the view will evaluate when page is rendering, so to get it work you will have to set team before the page is sent to browser.

This [guide](http://railsguides.net/cascading-selects-with-ajax-in-rails/) will help.

And if your lists are not very big to affect load times and page responsiveness you can just load and hide.